# Setting the background colour of a polygon

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to set the background colour of a polygon? I want to get a plot like this...

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 100
xx <- c(0:n, n:0)
yy <- c(c(0,cumsum(stats::rnorm(n))), rev(c(0,cumsum(stats::rnorm(n)))))

plot   (xx, yy, type="n", xlab="Time", ylab="Distance")
polygon(xx, yy, angle=45, density=10)
polygon(xx, yy+5, col="white")
polygon(xx, yy+5, angle=45, density=10, col="red")
```

But ideally without the penultimate line to set the background (I am plotting multiple polygons within a function I am writing). Is there an argument I can use in the final line that will negate the whole of the penultimate line? Cheers.

[image: Ugliness]

Comment: Do you really want the diagonal lines? Because you could just do it in a solid colour with one line.

Comment: yep, i really want diagonal lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My answer is 'no' - `help(polygon)` gives you `col` for filling the polygon but also uses it for the line shading colour if using `angle` and `density`.

This is a relic of the old days when your pen plotter could only pick up one pen at at time...

Doing it twice shouldn't be a problem. Write your own function that takes a polygon and two colour parameters and calls `polygon` twice.

Comment: -well doing it twice is a problem, i do not always want to plot diagonals. i think i will adapt the code to plot the white polygon first dependent on the arguments in my function. thanks for your efforts though, it is at least good to know that there is no simple answer that i am missing.